# Serial communication via scilab on linux

Tags: linux, scilab

I am trying to use  scilab for a project and I need to pass on some values to a robot via a serial port. 
I had done this successfully on Matlab. I have ported almost everything to Scilab now but I don't know how to pass those parameter through serial port.

Comment: take a look at [Scilab Serial Communication Toolbox (SSCT)](https://foadsf.github.io/ssct/)

Comment: you may see a demo [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/electronics/comments/b364ih/comment/eixfawy/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3).

Answer (score 2):

On the Sclilab site there are some modules, but they only work under Windows
http://atoms.scilab.org/

Answer (score 1):

I am the maintainer for the Serial Communication toolbox in Scilab. This works on Linux as well. You can find it here: http://atoms.scilab.org/toolboxes/serial. This is fairly easy to use- it has functions to establish communication with the serial port, to read from and write to the serial port, and to terminate communication with the serial port. Please let me know about any feedback or questions you may have. Thanks.